# React horizontal scroll component arrows doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to implement react horizontal scroll using React horizontal scrolling menu library, but when I use this component in my react app, it it displays the menu but the arrow are not working.

Here is the code of that component:

```js
import React from "react";
import { Box, Typography } from "@mui/material";
import { ScrollMenu, VisibilityContext } from "react-horizontal-scrolling-menu";

import Project from "./Project";
import Testimonial from "./Testimonial"

import LeftArrowImage from "../assets/images/left arrow.png";
import RightArrowImage from "../assets/images/right arrow .png";

const LeftArrow = () => {
  const { scrollPrev } = React.useContext(VisibilityContext);

  return (
    <Typography onClick={() => scrollPrev()} px={2}>
      <img src={LeftArrowImage} className="right-arrow" alt="right-arrow" />
    </Typography>
  );
};

const RightArrow = () => {
  const { scrollNext } = React.useContext(VisibilityContext);

  return (
    <Typography onClick={() => scrollNext()} px={2}>
      <img src={RightArrowImage} className="left-arrow" alt="right-arrow" />
    </Typography>
  );
};

function HorizontalScrollbar({ items, test }) {
  return (
    <Box mt={4} sx={{ display: { md: "block", xs: "none" } }}>
      <ScrollMenu LeftArrow={LeftArrow} RightArrow={RightArrow}>
        {items.map((item) => (
          <Box
            itemId={item.id} 
            title={item.id}
            key={item.id}
          >
            {test ? <Testimonial item={item} /> :  <Project item={item} />}
          </Box>
        ))}
      </ScrollMenu>
    </Box>
  );
}

export default HorizontalScrollbar;
```

Comment: I'm experiencing the same.  If I use static data to test, the arrows work, but not for dynamic data, even if I make the ScrollMenu dependant upon the presence of data.  :/

Comment: I tried to install the previous version but still got the same result. Please do you have any alternative that has the same functionality.

Comment: maybe you have to add a items.lenght conditionally to check out if items is iterable ?? i had the same issue, but i was missed out the itemId prop